# Unable to participate in discussion in Area 51

Tags: support, area-51

When I tried to join a discussion in Area 51, the system said I had to log in.

So I clicked on the link to log in, and logged in. Then I tried to join the discussion in Area 51 again, and the system still said I had to log in.

What should I do?